# Hiding an html attribute from codebehind

Tags: c#, html, css, .net

I have a string in which I am storing an html.

```
string receipt = "<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <table style="width: 100%">
  <tr id="trInsuranceInfo" style="line-height: normal;">
  </tr>
  <tr id="trCorpInfo" style="line-height: normal;">
  </tr>
  <tr id="trInvoiceDetails" style="line-height: normal;">
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
"
```

I am sending this html as an email 
I have to hide tr trInvoiceDetails from code behind  on particular condition.
i.e when I send that html via email trInvoiceDetails should not be there.

What is the best way to hide a tr from code behind ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
string receipt = "<html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
         <table style="width: 100%">
              <tr id="trInsuranceInfo" style="line-height: normal;"></tr>
              <tr id="trCorpInfo" style="line-height: normal;"></tr>
              %row%
         </table>
    </body>
</html>"
```

And then:

```
if(condition)
    receipt = receipt.Replace("%row%", ""); 
else
    receipt = receipt.Replace("%row%", "<tr id='trInvoiceDetails' style='line-height: normal;'></tr>");
```

Comment: @Kobey Douek  : html is stored  in string variable named receipt .
I have to write a condition such that when that html gets rendered on a page that tr gets hidden

Answer (score 0):

Add a nodes [trInvoiceDetailsStart] and [trInvoiceDetailsEnd] before and after tr trInvoiceDetails respectively.

Write a regx :

```
receipt = receipt.Replace(Regex.Match(receipt, @"\[trInvoiceDetailsStart\].*\[trInvoiceDetailsEnd\]", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value, string.Empty)
```